# C++ syntax to name file via variable and text

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a program that takes in the name of a file as an argument (example: books.txt), runs, and then outputs the results to a new text file. I need to name the output file with an addendum (example: books_output.txt).

The method that I tried was

```
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(argv[1] + "_output.txt", ofstream::out);
```

but this didn't compile.
How can I make this work?

Comment: s/`argv[1]`/`std::string(argv[1])`

Comment: your question is 'how do I concatenate strings in c++", google for that and see what you hit

Comment: @user0042 - thats going to depend on what version of c++ he is on, if ofstream.open supports string file name or not.

Comment: @pm100 The **current** standard does so. What else should I assume?

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but don’t call ‘open’. Just pass the file name to the stream’s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement should look like this (as mentioned in my comment):

```
outputFile.open(std::string(argv[1]) + "_output.txt", ofstream::out);
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^
```

assumed `argv[1]` comes from the standard `main()` signature

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

`argv[1]` is a `char*` pointer and you can't concatenate `char*` pointers that way.

As some people bother regarding support of obsolete C++ standard versions, the `std::ofstream::open()` signatures of earlier versions didn't support a `const std::string` parameter directly, but only `const char*`. In case you have that situation your statement should look like

```
outputFile.open((std::string(argv[1]) + "_output.txt").c_str(), ofstream::out);
```

Answer (score -3):

you cannot put a + between 2 C strings. Use std::string instead. Do this

```
ofstream outputFile;
std::string fname = std::string(argv[1]) + "_output.txt";
outputFile.open(fname.c_str(), ofstream::out);
```

More recent c++ versions allow

```
outputFile.open(fname, ofstream::out);
```

which reads nicer but means the same thing

Comment: Surely `argv[1] + "_output.txt"` is just as illegal outside the function as in? It can't know it's initializing a `string` and pre-convert either argument, can it? Just wrap in `std::string` on older C++ (`std::string(argv[1]) + "_output.txt"`), or use C++14 `std::string` literals (`argv[1] + "_output.txt"s` note trailing `s` on string literal). Or do two-step: `std::string fname = argv[1]; fname += "_output.txt";`

Comment: I'm using c++11. @pm100 and ShadowRanger both of your solutions worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: oops - my bad - i forgot to wrap arv in std::string